# Use of German "für"

Tags: translation

*Für* (German) can be translated to English *for* but in many cases *for* (English) has  different meaning in German. Can anyone tell me what to watch for in English to German translations? I would appreciate simple directions.

Comment: Hast Du schon ein Wörterbuch zu Rate gezogen und damit einen Teil Deiner Frage selbst beantworten können? Wir möchten kein Ersatz für Wöterbücher sein und nicht alles, was darin steht, wiederholen, daher bitten wir, herauszustellen, welche Fragen trotz eines Wörterbuchs nicht beantwortbar sind.

Answer (score 2):

The German word "*für*" **can** have the same meaning as the English word "*for*" 
(like in the sentence: 
" Ich habe Äpfel **für** dich." = "I've got apples **for** you.") but a lot of times they **do** **not**.

Examples:

- "Das gilt nicht **für** mich." = "That does not apply **to** me."
- "Du nimmst das **für** bare Münze." = "You take that **at** face value."
- " **Für** mich spielt das keine Rolle." = "That is irrelevant **to** me."

Since "für" can be an "Adverb" and a "Präposition" amongst other things, there is no easy answer to your question, I'm afraid. It depends a lot on context and meaning.